# Serialize/Deserialize encoder/decoder not working

Tags: objective-c, serialization, deserialization, initwithcoder

This is my first try at serializing data and I must not be doing something correctly because it's not working.  Perhaps it's because the class I am trying to serialize is a delegate or perhaps it's because of the way I'm populating the data or perhaps a million other things are wrong.  Can somebody who knows how to do this take a look at my code and give me some hints?  Please?

**Header file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol IDTemplateDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)saveTemplateForUI;
@end

@interface IDTemplate : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic) const char *templateData;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger templateSize;
@property (nonatomic) int templateQuality;
@property (nonatomic) int templateLocation;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<IDTemplateDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**Implementation File:**

```
#import "IDTemplate.h"

@implementation IDTemplate
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSData *data = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"templateData"];
        [data getBytes:(void *)_templateData length:_templateSize];
        _templateSize = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"templateSize"];
        _templateQuality = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"templateQuality"];
        _templateLocation = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"templateLocation"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:_templateData length:_templateSize];
    [encoder encodeObject:data forKey:@"templateData"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:_templateSize forKey:@"templateSize"];
    [encoder encodeInt:_templateQuality forKey:@"templateQuality"];
    [encoder encodeInt:_templateLocation forKey:@"templateLocation"];    
}

- (void)populateTemplate:(IDTemplate *)template
{
    self.templateData = template.templateData;
    self.templateSize = template.templateSize;
    self.templateQuality = template.templateQuality;
    self.templateLocation = template.templateLocation;
}

@end
```

**Calling code is here:**

self.template is a pointer to what should be my serialized class.
Maybe I can't do it this way?

```
- (void)generateTemplate:(cv::Mat)src
{
    Template template = *([self.cpp generateTemplate:src]);

    // self.template is a pointer to what should be my serialized class
    // maybe I can't do it this way?
    self.template = [[IDTemplate alloc] init]; 
    self.template.delegate = self;

    [self.template setTemplateData:template.getData()];
    [self.template setTemplateSize:template.getSize()];
    [self.template setTemplateQuality:template.getQuality()];
    [self.template setTemplateLocation:template.getLocation()];

    {// Setting up NSNotification for templateData
        NSMutableDictionary *templateData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
        [templateData setObject:self.template forKey:@"Template"];

        NSNotificationCenter *templateNote = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [templateNote postNotificationName:@"TemplateGenerated" object:nil userInfo:templateData];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you actually provided information about the problem. Don't make us read the code and guess. What issue are you having?

Comment: @rmaddy - The problem is that I am getting values back in my calling code but not the serialized values.  I put break points in my initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder and it's never getting in there.  I am wondering if it's not working because my IDTemplate class is a delegate.  I've got a few books and I can look for examples but I've never done this before and I'm not sure exactly how.  From what I have read, as long as I'm using NSCoding delegate it should just work.  Maybe I'm wrong.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: What should be calling `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder:`? Where do you attempt to serialize instances of `IDTemplate`?

Comment: @rmaddy - OK.  I will look at this tomorrow.  If I can come up with an answer, I will give you the points.  Just hang with me, please?  OK?  When I get an answer, you will be part of the results and I will give you the credit.  I promise.  :-)  Not that you need it, as you have plenty of points, but I like to give the credit to the ones who deserve it.  I won't cheat you.  I just need advice.  Thank you, again.  :-)

Comment: @rmaddy After sleeping on it and seeing both your's and Mundi's comments I realized that I might be totally wrong about what I am trying to do.  I don't really want to actually write out the data to a file.  I really want to dump out the char * value to a byte array.  I'm losing the value of the char * pointer when I need to be able to get it.  So I thought serializing it might be the answer.  Now, I'm second guessing that path.  I up voted your comment but now I guess I have a new question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing that in your init method you are using `_templateSize` for your before you have decoded it.

Comment: This is the solution of the problem I think.

Comment: @Mundi After sleeping on it and seeing both your's and rmaddy's comments I realized that I might be totally wrong about what I am trying to do.  I don't really want to actually write out the data to a file.  I really want to dump out the char * value to a byte array.  I'm losing the value of the char * pointer when I need to be able to get it.  So I thought serializing it might be the answer.  Now, I'm second guessing that path.  I up voted your comment but now I guess I have a new question.  Thank you.